# "as .. as" vs. "as much ... as"

Tags: grammaticality, comparisons

Using the expression **as (much) ... as**, I want to express that the quality or degree of someone's beauty is about the same as that of her intelligence. I'd like to know if it is correct to say either:

> 1. She is as smart as she is beautiful.
> 2. She is as much smart as she is beautiful.

Comment: _As much_ is just a general case; the _much_ isn't used if there's another adjective for _as_ to bind. That is, the second one is incorrect.

Comment: From BNC: "The story is as much inspirational as sad." Does the rule "the _much_ isn't used if there's another adjective for _as_ to bind" apply here?

Comment: How about "isn't often used"? There are options for everything; the idea that one structure is "correct" and all others are "incorrect" is a gradeschool oversimplification.

Comment: Isn't "as smart as beautiful" a way to go?

Comment: @tohecz, that's a possibility.  My thought is that   “as smart as she is beautiful” is slightly preferable to  “as smart as beautiful”; that choice is a question of style, not grammar.

Comment: @John Lawyer If it was *She's as much smart as me*  would it be a appropriate to use optionally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John Lawler noted in a comment, the second form (with *much*) is incorrect.  The first form,  “She is as smart as she is beautiful”, is grammatically correct, and does express the thought that her beauty is about the same as that of her intelligence (assuming there is some way to compare them).  Note that the sentence does not say she *is* smart or beautiful, merely that those qualities adhere to her in the same degree.

Comment: There is a strong implication that she is both smart and beautiful (ie that the interpretation _she is both smart and beautiful_ is intended) - this is the way the expression is normally used and should thus normally be understood. It is Grouchoesque to pick the logical rather than the conventional interpretation. Just like it would be Cooperesque to pick the logical, literal interpretation of _he's all ears_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, yes, frequently the intent may be to imply both smart and beautiful.  But many people speak sarcastically.